# Find embedded document with one field but not another

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection where each document contains an embedded collection; for example:

```
{
 cells: [
  {
   x: 1,
   y: 2
  },
  {
   x: 3
  }
 ]
 /* more fields not shown */
}
```

Is there a way to find those documents that have at least one document in the cells collection without a *y*-value (like the record shown here)?

Comment: I think [$elementMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) should help you here.

Comment: Something like this. `db.collection.find( { "cells.y": { $exists: false } } )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [$elementMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to achieve it:

```
db.col.find({
  cells: {
    $elemMatch: {
      y: {
        $exists: false
      }
    }
  }
});
```